# Is there software for generating encounters for D&D 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tools, tool-recommendation

I've been a long time player of D&D 3.5e, and I was wondering if there are any programs that can help me generate encounters, loot and experience.

I'm new to being a DM and have trouble following the books at times. The kind of program I'm looking for is something that I can enter the number of players, their level, type of monsters and how challenging I want it to be. Then can help me generate experience and loot at the end. I know it's a lot to ask for, but I figured that with everything on the Internet now that there has to be a program like this. I make good stories, it's just I'm bad at the after combat stuff.

Comment: Please be aware that a random encounter generator like you're asking will usually be based on comparing challenge ratings, and challenge ratings are usually not a good way to choose enemies for your party (platinum horrors are CR9 monsters with at will disintegrate and there's a CR3 crab with huge armor and grapple modifiers, and those are just the infamous ones... while a grick has very low HP and is a CR3. Plus, your party might be unequippd to fight swarms, or flying creatures, making them much more hard to cope with)

Answer (score 3):

There aren't a ton of great solutions that I am aware of (sadly) but I have used the generator at the following site:

http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/encounter/

The site provides a number of generators for 3.5 in addition to some system-agnostic material (that's either very 3.5 flavored or obviously not medieval fantasy).  The generators do a good job of providing balanced material, but a bad job of providing variety.  The first couple times you use the generator it will probably seem to work very well, but it will rapidly be apparent that it pulls from a small group of possible combinations, especially at high levels.  At very high levels, you used to pretty much only fight dragons, but that particular issue has been resolved.  The tool set is maintained and updated infrequently, but development is still ongoing and changes have, as far I have have seen, always been for the better.

The treasure generator (which I assume you will also want to use after using the encounter generator) does an excellent job with mundane non-useful equipment, (I once had a ranger drop his gloves of Dexterity +2 for a pair of  tooled leather gloves <% chance decoration> embossed with  imagery depicting unicorns driving evil fey out of a forest in silver thread.  I thought it was pretty awesome too, so we gave it some magic later), and does ok otherwise.

Both generators meet your requirements and have a number of other customizable options besides.

They work alright, but are certainly no substitute for GM preparation or a good premade adventure.

Answer (score 0):

My page has a monster database. It's rough in the edges but it might suit your needs:

http://rpg20.com/monsters.php

Only recently it allows to generate an encounter by EL (though randomly, with no control over the type of creatures allowed).

Other search options you might find useful is to get a list of monsters based on desired Challenge Rating or Hit Points (average). As a bonus, you *can* filter depending on Size, Type, Climate, and Terrain.

[Donjon's generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/encounter/) has been mentioned in another answer. And while it excels where my tools don't, I have some additional functionality that you cant find there.

Finally, I try my best to maintain a list of [tools from other people](http://rpg20.com/about.php#others) ([including monsters](http://rpg20.com/about.php#monsters)).

Answer (score -1):

Unearthed Arcana introduced the concept of totalling experience points to build an encounter and this was later formalized by Pathfinder. The current [Pathfinder](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gamemastering.html) simplifies this to CR equivalences. You choose the APL you want (3.5 would be EL), then you choose creatures of an appropriate CR (or equivalent) to add up to the APL you want. No calculator is really needed. The [donjon site](http://donjon.bin.sh/) is nice for automated generation of loot, but it is limited to OGL material.